# Fatal error: Call to a member function getOptionArray() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9, module, massaction

I am Created Custom Module "Recipe" (module name). when I add a mass action for status Magento throws an error like **"Fatal Error: Call to a member function getOptionArray() on a non-object "**

My Grid file code:

```
$statuses = Mage::getSingleton('recipe/status')->getOptionArray();
```

Also in my config.xml file code:

```
<resourceModel>recipe_mysql4</resourceModel>
```

So Can any one please tell me what was the mistake?

My Magento Version is: 1.9.2.3

Comment: have you created model file if yes then post code of status file

Comment: I am created model file but did not know what was the code I need to add code of status in model file

Comment: can you please tell me that?

Comment: can you post the `config.xml` file?

Comment: <global>
        <models>
            <recipe>
                <class>Sigmasolve_Recipe_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>recipe_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </recipe>
            <recipe_mysql4>
                <class>Sigmasolve_Recipe_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <recipe>
                        <table>recipe</table>
                    </recipe>
                </entities>
            </recipe_mysql4>
        </models>

Comment: Marius : here is my model section of config.xml file

Comment: Make sure you have the class `Sigmasolve_Recipe_Model_Status` with the method provided by Prashant Valanda and the defined constants `STATUS_ENABLED` and `STATUS_DISABLED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all option for status like as below

Add file at **Namespace/modulename/Model/Status.php**

```
   /**
     * Retrieve option array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    static public function getOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            self::STATUS_ENABLED    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Enabled'),
            self::STATUS_DISABLED   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Disabled')
        );
    }
```

Above is example of code

Comment: I put above code in collection.php file But magento gives same error

Comment: Updated answer please check it and create file at given path

Comment: Thanks Prashant : Resolved Error. But Now get "Please select Recipe(s)" this error , i am already select checkbox

Comment: public function massStatusAction()
    {
        $recipeIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('recipe');
  //print_r ($recipeIds);exit;
        if(!is_array($recipeIds)) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Please select Recipe(s)'));
        }